# NestedScrollView and CollapsingToolbarLayout quick scroll

Tags: android

I'm trying to made a collapsingtoolbar with a nestedscrollview. They work fine but if im on the bottom of the nestedscroll view and i do a really quick scroll (one rapid scroll touch) it scroll until the top of the nestedscrollview but the collapsingtoolbar doesn't expand.

Sorry about my english.

Code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:background="#fff">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="256dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="64dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/secimage"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarapp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Yo Yo" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Yo Yo" />


        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Yo Yo" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Yo Yo" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Yo Yo" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Yo Yo" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Yo Yo" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Yo Yo" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Yo Yo" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Yo Yo" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Yo Yo" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Yo Yo" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Yo Yo" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Yo Yo" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Yo Yo" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Yo Yo" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: This sounds like it's working as intended

Comment: Probably it's the usual function, but if i scroll it very quick with one touch. it stuck on the top of the nestedscrollview without expanding the appbar

Comment: Have the same issue. There should be an option to remove this behavior. It's really annoying.